# Django: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'company' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to make a url field in my detail view by passing two primary key in it...

This is what I have done in urls.py:

```
    url(r'^company/(?P<pk1>\d+)/groupdetail/(?P<pk2>\d+)/$',views.group1DetailView.as_view(),name='groupdetail'),
```

And in my views:

```
    def get_object(self):
        pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
        pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
        company = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
        group1 = get_object_or_404(group1, pk=pk2)
        return group1
```

I am getting error in this line:

```
company = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
```

And in my group1 list view I have done this:

```
<a href="{% url 'accounting_double_entry:groupdetail' pk1=company_details.pk pk2=group1_details.pk %}">{{group1.group_Name}}</a>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this code?

Thank you

Comment: The class name has the same as the variable name, so Python considers `company` to be a local variable.

Comment: Yeah that solves the problem...But why it is repeating the same primary key number for both case...

Comment: what do you mean? These use *different* primary keys (altough these *can* be the same, simply because the `id` "sequences" both start from 1, and increment, by default). Here you only perform the function to raise a 404, which is rather "exotic" :)

Comment: Suppose I click on a group which have a id 3 within a company of id 2...It is reading only the companys id and making the group id 2....The sequence should be company/2/groupdetail/3 but its coming company/2/groupdetail/2

Comment: Because you wrote `pk2=group1_details.pk`, instead of `pk2=group1.pk`.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that I was working on list view...Thank you@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: there's so much wrong, I dont even know where to start. Why are you querying 'company' when you're not returning it anyway?

Comment: @FeedTheWeb: because he wants to return a 404 if that URL points to no company, but I agree that the problem here is that one can "inject" a different company id.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem even if it 404's it should still return that

Comment: But it will return a 404 as HTTP result. Django in general ( and `get_object_or_404` in particular) uses the "exception mechanism" to raise a 404 *exception*, and the middleware translates this in a HTTP 404 response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah ok. I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function, you *assign* to a variable named `company`, so Python considers `company` to be a local variable, but at that moment unassigned, so you will need to use another variable name to avoid this:

```
def get_object(self):
    pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
    pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
    # make sure the variable name is different than the model name
    company_obj = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
    group1_obj = get_object_or_404(group1, pk=pk2)
    return group1_obj
```

Since you here however do not use `company_obj`, you might want to drop the variable name:

```
def get_object(self):
    pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
    pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
    get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
    group1_obj = get_object_or_404(group1, pk=pk2)
    return group1_obj
```

as an alternative, if your `group1` is "related" to `company`, and you want to chekck if that holds, it makes sense to filter on that company:

```
def get_object(self):
    pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
    pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
    company_obj = get_object_or_404(company, pk=pk1)
    group1_obj = get_object_or_404(group1, pk=pk2, company=company_obj)
    return group1_obj
```

> **Note**: [**PEP-8** [Python-doc]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?) advices class names to be written in *`CamelCase`*, whereas fields and local variables are written in *`lower_case`*. It is not uncommon to see something like `some_class = SomeClass()`, so because the camel case starts with an uppercase, clashes between local variables and classes, will never exist.