# Django auto assign value to foreign key when a form is submitted?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to render the name of the company into the database automatically whenever user submits the create form...

This is my model:

```
 class company(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="Company_Owner",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)

class group1(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    group_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    Company = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Company_group')
```

This is what I was trying to do in my views.py:

```
class group1CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class  = group1Form
    template_name = "accounting_double_entry/group1_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.User = self.request.user
        form.instance.Company = company
        return super(group1CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

But got this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<class 'company.models.company'>": "group1.Company" must be a "company" instance.
```

It worked for the User but is not working for the Company..

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong in this???

Thank you...

Comment: Please share full code

Comment: Company is the name of the field I have given in my group1 model ...And company is the model which is linked with group1 through foreign key...

Comment: `form.instance.Company = company`, where this `company` coming from ?

Comment: I have edited my code...

Comment: Its coming from company model

Comment: Another error because of object-class name clashes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603288/django-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-company-referenced-before-assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error might be in this line

```
form.instance.Company = company
```

here the **`company`** seems like a `Python class`, and it should be an **Instance of `company` class**

So, use an object/instance as

```
company_obj = company.objects.create(.....) # created a ne object
form.instance.Company = company_obj
```

**OR**

```
company_obj = company.objects.get(id=someid) # fetch new object from db
form.instance.Company = company_obj
```

---

Apart from the excpetion we advice you to follow the [PEP8 naming convetions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) in your code/projects

Comment: The unfortunate thing is that I already advised renaming yesterday (but probably in some other answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603288/django-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-company-referenced-before-assignment), but unfortunately the advise is not taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `c=company.objects.get(id=1)` use the query to fetch the company object you need.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.User = self.request.user
    c=company.objects.get(id=1)
    form.instance.Company = c
    return super(group1CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Do you need to fill the company with a exisitng company object or do you need to create a new as the user input the company name ?

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @JPG is correct. I will explain it in detail.

**First**, you have named your class name wrong. Class names follow CamelCase with first letter capital in python. Violating this would result in errors like this, where you confuse class name with instance name.

Comment: The unfortunate thing is that I already advised renaming yesterday (but probably in some other answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603288/django-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-company-referenced-before-assignment), but unfortunately the advise is not taken into account.

Comment: @Wliiem Van Onsem I have taken your advise into consideration into my main project...This is just a practice project I have made as because I am a learner now...

Comment: @Wliiem Van Onsem Well that happens in early stage. I was too naive to understand the importance of clean code when beginning to learn. Realization would come when OP suffers the same by his own actions :)

Comment: @NiladryKar: but the above experience (two problems in two days), should actually let you conclude that it is not good to do this. Like they say: "20% of development time should go into refactoring". Yes it takes time and sweat to refactor. But by not doing this, eventually the situation only gets worse.

Comment: @NiladryKar You should go through this, [PEP8 naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Yeah sure I will not make the same mistake again and have also updated my practice code....Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
class group1CreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class  = group1Form
    template_name = "accounting_double_entry/group1_form.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.User = self.request.user
        # form.instance.Company = company
        form.instance.Company = company.objects.get(pk='something') # OR
        # form.instance.Company = company.objects.create(stuff='stuff')
        return super(group1CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Also Class names should start with Upper Case(Pascal Case), and its attributes should be start with lowercase(snake_case). It's a common practice, follow it to avoid confusion

Comment: Can I do something like this 'c = company.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])'

Comment: i don't think so. What you should do is give an option to user to create or select company in your form.

Comment: Yeah was thinking of that also...Thank you@Vaibhav Vishal