# Django: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'property'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This are my models:

```
class company(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="Company_Owner",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)

class group1(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    group_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    Company = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Company_group') 

class ledger1(models.Model):
    User            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    Company         = models.ForeignKey(company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='Companys')
```

I have done this in my view:

```
from accounting_double_entry.models import group1,ledger1

model = company
paginate_by = 10

def get_queryset(self):
    return company.objects.filter(User=self.request.user).order_by('id')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(companyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['selectdates'] = selectdatefield.objects.filter(User=self.request.user)
    groupcach = group1.objects.filter(User=self.request.user, Company=company.pk,Master__group_Name__icontains='Capital A/c')
    groupcacb = groupcach.annotate(
        closing = Coalesce(Sum('ledgergroups__Closing_balance'), 0))

    groupcstcb = groupcacb.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('closing'), Value(0)))['the_sum']

    ledcah = ledger1.objects.filter(User=self.request.user, group1_Name__group_Name__icontains='Capital A/c')   
    ledcacb = ledcah.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Closing_balance'), Value(0)))['the_sum']

    total_cacb = groupcstcb + ledcacb
    context['capital'] = total_cacb
    return context
```

But getting this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'property'
```

I just cannot understand what this error mean. I just want to display the capital amount for all companies...

The error is in this line of code:

```
        groupcach = group1.objects.filter(User=self.request.user, Company=company.pk,Master__group_Name__icontains='Capital A/c')
```

Do anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: where is `group1` defined?

Comment: What is `group1`? Is it model name? Please provide info about it.

Comment: Yeah it is a model name...I have edited the question..

Comment: Please show `group1` model. As a note it's bad practice to name classes with lowecase. Use uppercase for that as `Group`.

Comment: Sorry for that...I have edited my question

Answer (score 3):

The variable `company` seems to be a class (from the line `model = company`). You should always use capital letters for your class names (i.e. name your model `Company` not `company`).

This line:

```
groupcach = group1.objects.filter(User=self.request.user, Company=company.pk,Master__group_Name__icontains='Capital A/c')
```

uses `company.pk` so `pk` is the property field on your class `company`. You haven't anywhere defined an object `company`.

My advice:

- Go back to refactor all your code to follow proper python conventions: classes are CamelCased, variables, properties and functions are snake_cased.
- Don't mix the two: `group_Name` or `Closing_balance` are wrong.
- `related_name` for a `ForeignKey` should be a plural.
- Then rerun your code and the errors will be more obvious (`company` not defined).

The reason for these convention is that they make it easier to avoid mistakes later on.

Comment: I'm afraid that recommending PEP-8 is a hopeless battle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603345/67579, three months ago, this was already an issue (and pointed out by *several* answers by *different* authors). Since nothing is done about it, of course the trouble remains.